# How do I get the gym rat badge on nba2k20

Tags: pc, nba2k20

Hello I have a character and with him I already won the NBA title and I thought that was how I got the
badge gym rat, but what do I do?

Comment: You question is a little light on the details, are there any more that you can share with us?  For instance, are there anything in the game saying what the requirements are for the badge?

Comment: I saw in a video that to get the gym badge (Gym rat) I need to win the NBA championship more after winning it does not appear to me

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you don’t only need to win the NBA anymore, you also need to have played 50 games this season

Answer (score 0):

To get this badge keep going to the Gym regularly and you will get it, it's relatively easy to do.